# Testing for an empty array in JavaScript Performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

http://jsperf.com/testing-for-empty-array

I was wondering what the best way to test for an empty array in JavaScript was and found some strange results. From what I can tell, you should never ever test using:

```
if (arr == true)
  // do stuff
```

which I thought was interpreted identical to:

```
if (arr)
  // do stuff
```

Is there a reason why using `arr == true` is significantly slower?

Comment: isn't arr.length !== 0 even faster?

Comment: Isn't `arr == true` always false? Whether empty or not?

Comment: But shouldn't it go through the same tests in the `if (arr)` case?

Comment: @alFReDNSH I guess you're right. I just added it because I thought they were equivalent. Nice catch!

Comment: Even `if (arr)` is always true. Whether empty or not.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `if (a.length)`.

Comment: @alFReDNSH: `if(someUndeclaredArray)`

Comment: Thats weird because I read a blog post a while back that showed a shortcut to determing if a jQuery element existed using: `if  ($('#something-that-may-exist'))`...

Comment: @ElliotBonneville That is not an array if not declared, testing for emptiness is very different than testing for existence.

Comment: @alFReDNSH: Was responding to "...`if(arr)` is always true"

Comment: I would think testing for a first element would be fastest because then it doesn't have to traverse.

Comment: @RyanAllred - The first element of the array could be the value `undefined`. JavaScript doesn't have to traverse the array to determine its length. Note that `if(arr)` will always be `true` if `arr` is an array, empty or not. You need to test `arr.length` (and possibly use `Array.isArray(arr)`) to test whether `arr` is an empty array.

Comment: @RyanAllred You can have an array of `[undefined]`. The length is 1 and is not empty, but if you test for the first element, you might think it is empty!

Comment: You're right, but if I have an undefined in an array that I don't expect to contain undefined, then I have bigger problems.

Comment: @RyanAllred Don't rely on the benchmark like this. jsperf makes sure the browser doesn't use their optimizing compiler in here, which in a case you need performance, you will be using optimizing compiler in your app.Then the performance results might be even different for storing different things in array(like small integers which can be optimized), or if the array is empty or not. The best is that just use !a.length or a.lengt`, then later if you profile and found out you need to optimize that bit, you can replace it with other things if it makes significant improvement in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only good way to test if an array is empty is with `arr.length`.

Let see different case.

1. `if(arr === true)` will always be false since array is not a boolean.

   `if(arr !== false && arr !== true)` will return true for the same reason!
2. `if(arr)` will return true or false, it depend if the array is set. If the `var arr = []`, it will return true, but it is an empty array.

   In fact, even if the var is not an array, it will return true.
3. `if(arr[0])` will return true if there is a value in the cell with the index 0. Even there, it doesnt mean it is empty, because you can set a cell like that `var arr=[]; arr[1] = 'value'` and `arr[0]` will return false because it is not set, but the array have a length of 2 (with one cell).

Finally, the best way to see if an array is empty is like that : `if(arr && arr.length)`.

checking if `arr` exist not needed if you know that you have created the array, but else, it will prevent any errors. Then, you check the length of the array and if you haven't changed the value like that : `arr.length = 1000`, it will tell you if the array is empty.

Comment: Actually, `console.log([1] == true)` will print `true`. Remember that in JavaScript, `==` does automatic type conversion.

Comment: in #3, if you set `arr[0]`, the length will be 2. Just saying.

Comment: The [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) is pretty clear in that aspect. `[1] == true` => `[1] == 1` => `'1' == 1` => `1 == 1` => `true`

Comment: There's a complex series of type conversions going on. First, `true` is converted to a number (which will be `1`). Then, the array is converted to a primitive, which will be the string `'1'` (a comma-separated list of the values in the array). Then the string is also converted to a number. If the numbers match, then the two values are considered equal. (Note that the left side may be `NaN`.)

Comment: ^ Yes that is way more well explained than my comment. `=]`

Answer (score 2):

It has to convert the array first to an empty string and from there into a boolean to compare against `true`, because you can't compare an array directly with a boolean. Casting is expensive.

Comment: why does it have to do that?

Comment: Why does it have to do what? Compare? Cast?

Comment: @chris - The rules for equality comparison, including what type conversions are required, is spelled out in section 11.9.3 of the [EcmaScipt specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262%20edition%205.1,%20June%202011.pdf).

Comment: why cast to string? an object is always truthy, is it not?

Comment: Here's a direct link to [#11.9.3](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3). @chris step 8-9 calls `ToPrimitive` on the object on the second pass of the algorithm (first one casts the boolean to number). The `ToPrimitive` of an array is the string representation of its elements concatenated by `,`.

Comment: So in sum, an object is always truthy (save for some host objects) if you use it isolated inside the condition as in `if (arr)`, but `== true` does not mean that it is truthy. `[] == true //false` as an empty string (the `ToPrimitive` of the array) is falsy.